# Has anyone integrated Salesforce Commerce Cloud (SFCC) with any messaging technologies?

Tags: commerce-cloud, b2c

I'm looking for examples of how others might have solved for this.

Did you build a custom cartridge?

Did you leverage some externally running agent to retrieve data by OCAPI (or Commerce Cloud APIs)? ...(i.e., a "pull" strategy)

I've read the documentation, spent many nights searching Google, searched the Salesforce Commerce Cloud Marketplace, spoken with several Salesforce Commerce Cloud expert consultants & system integration firms - but it appears ***no one*** is aware of anyone else doing this before.

Answer (score 0):

Technically any messaging system can fetch or push data towards Commerce Cloud B2C by using the out-of-the-box OCAPI / SCAPI Rest API.

There is no need for a "cartridge" unless you want to build particular use-case APIs.